# Running a bash program every day at the same time

Tags: bash, unix, alarm

I've written a program using the bash shell that I want to use to wake myself up in the morning (pulls up the weather, plays some music, etc.). How do I make my Mac OSX run the program every day at 7:00 AM automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Mac OSX is BSD and BSD is Unix, you can use the Cron-Daemon.
Just edit your cron-file with

```
crontab -e
```

an put in the following line

```
 0 7 * * *     /path/to/your/script/here
```

More details here: [article about Cron in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Answer (score 3):

You can use cron to schedule it to be used every day at time you desire

Check the following link:
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2001020700163714